# Facebook Likebox Plugin Stopped Working?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Has anyone else seen any issues recently with the Facebook Likebox Plugin?  One of my client sites has stopped displaying posts and has done since sometime last week at least.  The specific plugin is here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-box-for-pages/

Currently even Facebooks own demo page isn't working for me in Chrome (PC, version 31.0.1650.57 m), it displays nothing?  Chrome is logged into my Facebook account.

In Firefox the demo is working but my client page placed in the devloper site is not displaying posts.  I know Facebook can change privacy settings (it's caught me out before!) so I took a post off the client page and put this into the Embedded Posts plugin and it displayed correctly so there are Public posts (in Firefox, again no display at all in Chrome for me, not even with the Facebook example).

I am not logged into Facebook in the Firefox Browser but am in Chrome, using the Facebook Plugin site in a Chrome Incognito Window does give the same results as Firefox, displays example data but not posts for client page.

Does anyone have any ideas what could be causing this?  It certainly highlights how aware you have to be when you rely on 3rd parties!

Answer (score 0):

The facebook page might have to change country restrictions. If you don't see the box on a certain browser check to make sure you are logged into facebook on that browser.

This article explains what might possibly be your problem.

http://www.andreavahl.com/facebook/why-your-facebook-like-box-is-not-showing-up.php